# On-Premises Deployments for SharePoint 2013 Apps?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I configured all requirements for deploy Apps from store and i can access all apps, browsing and download available after find it on apps i can add it but;

> This page can't be displayed

•Make sure the web address http://apps-6967e27a413f60.xxx.abc.local:2014 is correct.

---

any solution?

Comment: Have you configured the isolated app domain? Also, is your web application host header based?

Comment: Yes, configured .. i can access all apps store!

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

> The problem was that the web application of my developer site was host
>   header based. The Url was something like `http://intranet.contoso.com`.
>   As soon as I created a site without host header like
>   `http://sitename:80`, I was able to deploy the apps.

See this for more information:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-isolated-app-domain.html