# SharePoint app this page can't be displayed?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

I configured all requirements for deploy Apps from store and i can access all apps, browsing and download. On trying to load the App, I get an error as follows:

> This page can't be displayed
>
> •Make sure the web address http://apps-6967e27a413f60.xxx.abc.local:2014 is correct.

Comment: Already asked here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92186/on-premises-deployments-for-sharepoint-2013-apps